# How to expose metrics to http in dropwizard?

Tags: java, metrics, dropwizard, codahale-metrics

I am reading following document:
https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.2.0/getting-started.html

I've added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-servlets</artifactId>
    <version>${metrics.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

But what to do next ? How to access metrics ?

Comment: What is unclear about the getting started guide? It contains examples on how to add metrics in code, and multiple options to retrieve metrics report (console, http or jmx). Please describe the problem you’re facing and what you have tried.

Comment: @slindenau I have metrics in code and  I see them in console after adding ConsoleReporter. It is clear. Now I want to execute GET request and receive metrics. In guide I've found that only dependency is required.  But where I can find metrics ? what URL should I use ?

Comment: Quote from the bottom of the page: `From there on, you can map the servlet to whatever path you see fit`. Looks like you need to manually map it.

Comment: @slindenau
Which Servlet ? I AdminServlet ? MetricsServlet ?

Comment: @slindenau Thanks, it helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/72790421/2674303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to register AdminServlet but this helped me:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(MetricRegistry metricRegistry){
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new MetricsServlet(metricRegistry),"/metrics/*");
}
```